# Basecamp classic api: how to add a new line into comment body

Tags: c#, api, basecamp

I use classic basecamp api, and I want to add a new line into comment body. I have been tried to use Envirovent.NewLine and CDATA, but basecamp remove it from result text.
Do anybody know how to do it? It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a comment through a rest call reveals a `div` tag within the xml structure for a line break

Call

```
GET https://#{account_url}.basecamphq.com/comments/#{comment_id}.xml
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
 <comments count="1" type="array">  
  <comment>  
   ...  
   <body>
     <div> Comment-Text line ONE</div>  
     <div> Comment-Text line TWO</div>  
   </body>  
   ...  
  </comment>  
 </comments>
```

However, posting xml to the API applying the same structure as above results in the following terrible looking comment in Basecamp Classic:

> {"div"=>[" Comment-Text line ONE", " Comment-Text line TWO"]}

The CDATA tag does work but has to be implemented in the following manner:

```
  <comment><![CDATA[  
   <body>
     <div> Comment-Text line ONE</div>  
     <div> Comment-Text line TWO</div>  
   </body>  
  </comment>]]>
```

Or an example of feeding dynamic content with php

```
$comment_xml = "<comment><body><![CDATA[<div>Person: " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . "</div><div>Email: " . $email . "</div>]]></body></comment>";
```

`<div>` and `<br />` tags will both work for new lines

Answer (score 0):

I tried with \n , but it didn't worked..

```
table_config = [
    {
        'dbName': f'gomez_datalake_{env}_{team}_{dataset}_db',
        'table': 'ConFac',
        'partitionKey': 'DL_PERIODO',
        'schema': [
            ['TIPO_DE_VALOR', 'STRING', 2, None,
             "CÓDIGO DEL PARÁMETRO DE SISTEMA."
             "EJEMPLOS:"
             "UF:  VALOR DE LA UF"
             "IP:  VALOR DEL IPC"
             "MO:  MONEDA"
             "IV:   VALOR DEL VA"
             "UT:  VALOR DEL UTM"],
            ['ORIGEN', 'STRING', 4, None, "IDENTIFICADOR DE USUARIO"]
        ]
```